# how to run scala sbt-native-packager for a appJS/appJVM cross-build project

Tags: scala, sbt-native-packager

The sbt-native-packager can make a zip file with all dependencies and a script to run_

`$ sbt universal:packageBin`

I have a scala web application, using cross-build (appJS for front-end and appJVM for back-end).

How do I run this packager for the appJVM? 
I've tried as follows, but it does not accept the command:

`$ sbt appJVM/universal:packageBin`

Here it is the build.sbt project, from https://www.scala-js.org/doc/project/cross-build.html

```
...

lazy val foo = crossProject.in(file(".")).
  settings(
    name := "foo",
    version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  ).
  jvmSettings(
    // Add JVM-specific settings here
  ).
  jsSettings(
    // Add JS-specific settings here
  )

lazy val fooJVM = foo.jvm
lazy val fooJS = foo.js
```

How do I run this packager for the appJVM?

And how I include the file generated by `sbt appJS/fullOptJS`?

And some other static files?

---

***Update with Ivan response***

build.sbt:

```
import sbtcrossproject.CrossPlugin.autoImport.{crossProject, CrossType}

val sharedSettings = Seq(
    scalaVersion := "2.12.8",
)

lazy val app =
    crossProject(JSPlatform, JVMPlatform)
        .in(file("."))
        .settings(sharedSettings)
        .jsSettings(
        )
        .jvmSettings(
            libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % "10.1.9"
      ),
    )

lazy val backend = project
  .enablePlugins(UniversalPlugin)
  .enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
  .dependsOn(app.jvm)
  .settings(
    mainClass in Compile := Some("com.example.EchoServer")
  )

lazy val frontend = project
  .enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin)
  .dependsOn(app.js)

backend
  .settings(
      Seq(
      resourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
        Seq(
          (fullOptJS in Compile in frontend).value,
          (fastOptJS in Compile in frontend).value
        ).map { js =>
          val resource = (resourceManaged in Compile).value / "public" / "assets" / js.data.name
          IO.write(resource, IO.read(js.data))
          resource
        }
      }.taskValue
    )
  )
```

and run:

```
$ sbt backend/universal:packageBin
34: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[sbt.Def.Setting[Seq[sbt.Task[Seq[java.io.File]]]]]
 required: Int
      Seq(
         ^
[error] Type error in expression
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following structure.

Define a shared project that needs to be cross-compiled for JS and Scala.

```
lazy val shared = CrossPlugin.autoImport
  .crossProject(JSPlatform, JVMPlatform)
  .crossType(CrossType.Pure)
  .jvmSettings(???)
  .jsSettings(???)

lazy val sharedJvm = shared.jvm

lazy val sharedJs = shared.js
```

Add project that contains a Main class.

```
lazy val backend = project
  .enablePlugins(UniversalPlugin)
  .enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
  .dependsOn(sharedJvm)
```

Add `web` project containing web related code.

```
lazy val web = project
  .enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin)
  .dependsOn(sharedJs)
```

And finally, attach resources from `web` compiled into JS to `backend`.

```
backend
  .settings(
    Seq(
      resourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
        Seq(
          (fullOptJS in Compile in web).value,
          (fastOptJS in Compile in web).value
        ).map { js =>
          val resource = (resourceManaged in Compile).value / "public" / "assets" / js.data.name
          IO.write(resource, IO.read(js.data))
          resource
        }
      }.taskValue
  )
```

Main class needs to service compiled JS from `public/assets`, as configured in sbt, and any other web resources from its class path.

Comment: I've updated the question with your suggestion, but it still fails. See the question again.

Comment: Thx! I've updated the question with your info. running `sbt backend/universal:packageBin` works if I remove the `resourceGenerators`. Otherwise it fails with `error: type mismatch; found   : Seq[sbt.Def.Setting[Seq[sbt.Task[Seq[java.io.File]]]]], required: Int`. I've read the doc on https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Generating-Files.html but I do not see how to set the resourceGenerators inside a `settings` section.